# How to pass req.params to middleware in Express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'd like to serve a file listing page using `express.static` and `serve-index` Express middlewares (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index). Instead of hardcoding the root path I'd like it to be fetched from database based on an id in the url.

The middlewares can be used like this

```
app.use('/logs/:id', express.static('C:\\log\\root\\dir'), serveIndex('C:\\log\\root\\dir'));
```

The question is how to pass req.params.id to the middlewares. I tried with a wrapper function like this but it didn't work:

```
const mymw = (middleware, id) => {
    const rootDir = getRootDirFromDb(id);
    return middleware(rootDir);
}

app.use('/logs/:id', (req, res) => mymw(express.static, req.params.id), (req, res) => mymw(serveIndex, req.params.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the middleware definition to `app.use` and the `req` object will be available in your middleware.

```
const mymw = (req, res, next) => {
  // req.params is available here.
  // you can call next() here to move to the next controller
}

app.use('/logs/:id', mymw, (req, res, next) => {
  // also do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's possible to read stuff from req.params in my own middlewares but `serve-index` or `express.static` don't read the root path from there but instead like this: `serveIndex(rootPath)`. Is it somehow possible to pass parameters via `next()` or how could I get this working?